# Convert gl_FragCoord range to fragment range

Tags: mathematics, glsl

I'm working with shaders so far, but I'm not sure how I can make my shader gl_FragCoord relative to the window. To be more clear, this is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I'm looking to achieve no matter where I place the fragment on the screen:

[image]

As you can see, the shader take the whole window as the refference canvas insted of the fragment. I'm playing with ranges and division based on resolution and fragment size/position, but couldn't figure it out.

The second image was compiled based on hardcoded data, need to find a general solution..

EDIT: This is my vert & frag glsl code:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main() {
    vec2 fp = vec2(position.x, position.y);
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0 );
};
```

$

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main() {
    vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy/vec2(800., 600.);

    float r = 0.4 / 2.0;
    float c = smoothstep(r, r - 0.01, distance(pos, vec2(0.5)));

    color = vec4(vec3(c) * vec3(0.0, 0.5,1.0), 1.0);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resolution is undoubtedly not actually 800 by 600, as the following shadertoy program gives the output you desire, with the only change being the proper resolution is used to divide.  You also don't need to pass in coordinates at all, look at this explanation of [gl_FragCoord](http://www.txutxi.com/?p=182)

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy/ iResolution.xy;

    float r = 0.4 / 2.0;
    float c = smoothstep(r, r - 0.01, distance(pos, vec2(0.5)));

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(c) * vec3(0.0, 0.5,1.0), 1.0);
}
```

Test it out [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/new)

EDIT:

You appear to be hinting that you are actually using 400 x 300 resolution, if that is the case, my answer is 100% correct, to fix your problem *divide by 400 and 300 instead of 800 and 600!*

so instead of

```
vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy/vec2(800., 600.);
```

do this

```
vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy/vec2(400., 300.);
```

Or if your resolution is different do this where resolution_x and resolution_y are the values for your *actual resolution*...

```
vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy/vec2([resolution_x]., [resolution_y].);
```

If you want this to work with all resolutions *you will still need to pass the resolution to the shader*.

I recommend changing your shader to this and passing a resolution uniform in.

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
uniform vec2 screenResolution

void main() {
    vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy/screenResolution.xy;

    float r = 0.4 / 2.0;
    float c = smoothstep(r, r - 0.01, distance(pos, vec2(0.5)));

    color = vec4(vec3(c) * vec3(0.0, 0.5,1.0), 1.0);

};
```

Comment: Shadertoy takes the whole window as the refference, not a fragment obeject. 800x600 is the window resolution, the object is 400x300, in this case..

Comment: @alex1997  what are you talking about? This is computed per fragment, I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  Clearly your resolution is wrong, shader toy uses actual glsl to display.  Yes you don't have access to the uniform iResolution, however as long as you actually *have the correct resolution* your shader will work. clearly what ever you are dividing your frag coords by isn't going to work.

Comment: Now I see what you did there, you divided `r` with 2 which means multiplication of `fragmenWidth/windowWidth` (this is what I did to get the circle in the fragment), but if I want to render a circle in a rectagle e.q 400x300 at position (30, 200), it won't work at all since the offest should be takken in consideration untill there's something better like gl_TextCoord[].xy..  see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702694/making-shader-takes-vertexarray-as-canvas-instead-of-the-window

Comment: @alex1997  ***what are you talking about I litterally copied your code and changed only the iResolution part...*** you ***ALSO*** did that exact same thing with the r.  It seems like your resolution is 400 x 300, in which case my answer is 100% correct, you didn't actually divide gl_fragCoord.xy by the right numbers (you use 800 by 600)

Comment: If I'm applying your code to the first image case ( where the rectangle is positioned at `off1xoff2` it won't work, the circle it won't be in the rectangle..this is what I'm really trying to fix and got the idea to get the size of 1px in [0,1] range than multiply it by my offset and add it to the `pos` value. That should do the trick, but seems that I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @alex1997  You need to edit your question, my answer actually answers your question "I'm working with shaders so far, but I'm not sure how I can make my shader gl_FragCoord relative to the window".  If you want the circle to be in an arbitrary rectangle that is a different story, what you are describing right now has nothing to do with your current question.   Honestly nothing with offsets appears in your question, so I'm not even sure what you are talking about there.

Comment: I'm really glad that you offered to help me and it's my mistake that I didn't tell about offsets, but I specified that `this is what I'm looking to achieve no matter where I place the fragment on the screen:`. Slowly, but surely I'll be able to achieve what I get, but I'm not sure if it'll be the right way that's why I posted here in case there's some GLSL utils that I didn't hear about them..

Comment: I did pressed enter by mistake, check my reply now. However I've seen your edit, but I want the method to not be hardcoded, 400x300 is an arbitrary example. If I won't find what I need I'll close the topic, mark this as the good answer and maybe reopen it later one with much more details than this..

Comment: @alex1997 Ah, ok, it is not very clear what you meant by "and this is what I'm looking to achieve no matter where I place the fragment on the screen" since *you* don't place fragments, I believe you mean "I'm looking to create a circle inside of a quad of vertices no matter the quads location on the screen"

Comment: The circle is an arbitrary example too, the main goal is to achieve rendering shaders on quads like I would have rendered the shader on the whole window. Basically, the shader should take the quad as global instead of the window. There was something like gl_TextCoord in version  120, but in version 330 should be a different way to do it..

Comment: For some reasong, dividing the gl_FragCoord will place my shader in the bottom left corner always. That's a good start, I'll need to implement the offsets too and that should do the trick. After I manage to realize that, I'll try to work do the data that I send it to the vertex shader to make it easier to work with it

Comment: @alex1997 oh wow, ok, so that is is a whole completely different question, I would recommend making a new one, "how to render fragment shader onto quad as if the quad is its own screen space" should be descriptive enough.  It is possible an answer already exist for that though.

Comment: That should be the suitable good title, I'll close this and if I get no solution, I'll try to open something with more details this time!

Answer (score 0):

We use the built-in `gl_FragCoord` value, which gives us the `(x, y)` coordinates (in pixels) of the current fragment in the frame buffer. We divide this by the resolution width and height (e.g. 800, 600) to get values between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy
```

Note that gl_FragCoord value uses a lower left origin, so (32, 10) would mean 32 pixels to the right, 10 pixels up from the bottom. However, since our circle is symmetrical and located at center, we do not need to worry about this difference in our specific demo.

We subtract `(0.5, 0.5)` so that we can determine the length from center, rather than lower-left (the origin).

```
//determine center
vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy) - vec2(0.5);
```

We will use GLSL's built-in length() method to determine the length from the center point. Fragments at the center will have a length of zero (i.e. black), and it will increase as we move outward (i.e. into white/gray). We can test the shader so far:

```
//our screen resolution, set from Java whenever the display is resized
uniform vec2 resolution;

//"in" attributes from our vertex shader
varying vec4 vColor;

    void main() {

        //determine origin
        vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy) - vec2(0.5);

        //determine the vector length of the center position and using step function for drawing circle
        float circle = step(length(position),0.5);

        //show our length for debugging
        gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3(length), 1.0 );
    }
```

https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson3

https://thebookofshaders.com/07/

Comment: Yeah, I what you did there, but I don't see the fragment offset takken in consideration. Your code will render an circle in the middle of the screen (The way I'm doing it with distance is better because it won't require substracting `vec2(0.5)` to modify origin), but if I want to render a circle in a rectagle e.q 400x300 at position (30, 200), it won't work at all..

Comment: This seems to do the trick, but it uses #version 120 stuffs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702694/making-shader-takes-vertexarray-as-canvas-instead-of-the-window